# Installing Octave on Ubuntu Mate on Raspberry pi 3

Tags: ubuntu-mate, raspberrypi, octave

I have Ubuntu Mate on a raspberry pi 3 and I'm trying to install Octave without success so far. I got (sorry if its not accurate, I translated from Spanish):

```
$  sudo apt-get -y install octave
 octave : dependency: octave-common (= 4.0.0-3ubuntu9.2) but 4.2.2-1~octave~xenial2 will be installed

$ sudo apt-get -y install octave-common
octave-common is in its more recent version (4.2.2-1~octave~xenial2).
```

what am I doing wrong or what I'm not doing?

Comment: It seems that your repositories are not correct. Please add output of `apt-cache policy octave octave-common` to the question. Also please note that 16.04 LTS has octave packages [versioned at *4.0.0-3ubuntu9.2*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=octave).

Answer (score 1):

I have `octave` version 4.2.2-1 installed in my Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (amd64). And `octave-common` is and should be the same version.

```
$ LANG=C apt-cache policy octave octave-common
octave:
  Installed: 4.2.2-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 4.2.2-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 4.2.2-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
octave-common:
  Installed: 4.2.2-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 4.2.2-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 4.2.2-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Maybe it helps, if you run

```
sudo apt update
```

and maybe also

```
sudo apt install -f
```

and then try again with

```
sudo apt install octave
```